# Can't seem to figure this integral out

Tags: calculus, integration

I have an integral here that I'm trying to figure out.

$$ \int 7\sin^2x \cos^4x\  dx $$

Here's what I got as an answer:

$$ \frac{7}{16}x-\frac{7}{64}\sin4x+\frac{7}{12}\sin2x + C $$

However, I'm doubting myself and the check didn't seem to produce good results.  I can give some steps if you want. I filled a whole page with work, and it seems like it should be easier than that.  Any ideas?

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+7sin%28x%29%5E2+cos%28x%29%5E4  Click on "show steps" for one possible derivation.

Comment: @BillCook: That uses the reduction formula though.  I'd rather stick to identities and such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use $\sin(x)\cos(x) = {1 \over 2}\sin(2x)$ and $\cos^2(x) = {1 + \cos(2x) \over 2}$ and your integral is
$$7 \int\left({1 \over 2}\sin(2x)\right)^2 {1 + \cos(2x) \over 2}\,dx$$
$$= {7 \over 8}\int \sin^2(2x)\,dx  + {7 \over 8}\int\sin^2(2x)\cos(2x)\,dx$$
The first term is just a $\sin^2$ integral, and the second can be dealt with by a $u$ substitution $u = \sin^2(2x)$.

Comment: That looks easy.  I actually did the first step that you suggested, but somehow I made it a lot harder than it needed to be.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hmm, I did it again when I had the chance and I got this: $$ \frac{7}{16}x-\frac{7}{64}\sin4x+\frac{7}{12}\sin^32x + C $$  Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to check according to WolframAlpha.

Comment: @confused I think the coefficient before the $\sin^3(2x)$ term should be ${7 \over 48}$. In other words your $du$ should be $2 \cos(2x)\,dx$ and not $2 du = \cos(2x)\,dx$.

Comment: Yep, I just found that out.  I had taken the *antiderivative* of $u$ instead of the *derivative*.  However, even with that coefficient it still doesn't check.

Comment: There are multiple ways of writing a given function sometimes, so most likely they are the same function but in different forms.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Try writing $\sin^2(x)=1-\cos^2(x)$ and then use the identity $\cos^2(x)=\frac{1+\cos(2x)}{2}$.

Comment: ...some algebra...apply identities again...some algebra...pain and suffering.

Comment: I'll give that a shot.  I find it hard to know where to start on these things.

Comment: "pain and suffering" - my take was "algebra, sweat, and tears"...